# Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) in Header

Tags: css, cumulative-layout-shift

I am having a trouble with some Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) appearing from the footer in the header. The social icons + the text 'discover' appears behind the main logo.

Domain is [www.minoar.com](http://www.minoar.com)

Some of the CSS here from it is:

```
#footerSocial {
top: 27px;
display: block;
 
#footerSocial {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
padding: 5px 50px 0 50px;
```

However I am not sure how to fix this and make it static to the footer. I'll appreciate your advises. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Just try

```
position:sticky
```

for your footer section. This will fix the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).